# Interact function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a program that loads a list of names which you can find and add names to the list. I have to write a parse_command function which takes a string representing a command and its arguments and returns a pair consisting of the command and a tuple containing the commands arguments if its a valid command with the right number of arguments. Otherwise it returns the pair (None, None)

The output should look something like this:

```
>>>parse_command('e')
('e',())
>>>parse_command('f')
(None, None)
>>>parse_command('f John Smith')
('f', ('John Smith',))
>>>parse_command('a John Smith, Washington DC, 02532223, 6 August')
('a', ('John Smith', 'Washington DC', '02532223', '6 August'))
>>>parse_command('a John Smith, Washington, 1234')
(None, None)
>>>parse_command('x')
(None, None)
```

So far I have this:

```
def parse_command(command_string):
i = command_string
if i[0] == 'e':
    return ('e', ())
elif i[0] == 'f':
    command = i[1:]
    if bool(command) == True:
      return ('f', (command,))
    elif bool(command) == False:
        return (None, None)
elif i[0] == 'a':
    command = i[1:]
    section = i.split(',')
    if len(section) == 4:
        return ('a', tuple(i[2:].split(', ')))
    else:
       return (None, None)
```

Everything works fine and I get the outputs I should but I want to write an interact function. So if the user wants to look up a name or add a name, they can do so easily. To add someone to the list the user would type 'a' followed by the person with all their details. To find someone they would type 'f' followed by the person's name. If they wanted to exit the program they would simply type 'e'. If 'a, e or f' aren't used 'Invalid Command' would be returned. An example would be like this:

```
>>>List of Names: names.csv
>>>Command: f John Smith
John Smith: Chicago, 12345, 4 July
>>>Command: f roeuh eoruhg
roeuh eoruhg Unknown Friend
Invalid Command: f
>>>Command: a John Smith, LA, 12345, 3 July
John Smith is already a friend 
>>>Command: a Roger Little, Texas, 12345, 9 August
>>>Command: f Roget Little
Roger Little: Texas, 12345, 9 August
>>>Command: e
Saving changes...
Exiting...
```

So far I have written this (load_names, add_name and display_name are already written):

```
def interact():
names = load_names(raw_input('List of Names: '))
ended = False
while True:
    result = parse_command(raw_input('Command: '))
    if result is not (None, None):
       if result[0] == 'f':
          return display_name(result[1], names)
          pass
       elif result[0] == 'a':
          return add_name(result[1:], names)
          pass
       elif result[0] == 'e':
          return 'Saving Changes...' + /n 'Exiting...'
          ended = True 
          pass
```

I'm a little bit stuck and am looking for some help on the interact function, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you want to take a look at the [`cmd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module...

Comment: I am sorry, this code is horrible, and unreadable, I have read your question 2 times, and I have almost no idea what you are trying to do here. I recommend you take a time out from coding, and learn a bit more about the things you are trying to do, find something similar to what you are doing and study it. Because whatever it is you are doing, it is not working.

Comment: Do you mean for the interact function @InbarRose ? Basically, to add someone to the list you use 'a' followed by their details. To find someone you use 'f' followed by their name. 'e' simply exits the program.

Comment: And how was anyone supposed to understand this? (we can't read your mind) you did not give any indication as to what is actually going on, you just pasted your code.

Comment: Sorry @InbarRose I thought I had put that in there, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement a method to interact with a persistent object like a file or database outside of the code. I would recomend using [Python SQLite](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/). Since the language you use suggests an assignment, and your own request is that of help, I have not provided a full solution.

Comment: I've written a function to load a file and to save to a file. Would rather keep the code as basic as possible, if that makes sense? Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: No, it does not make sense, you will find very soon that a file does not give you enough functionality. What you are designing *is* a database. So why not have it be one? SQLite is designed especially for you, it is a simple file, not a real database, and it acts like a database as long as you use the API. Very simple, and proper coding.

Comment: It's a homework task, I'm only doing what the instructions say.